# Can scoping create objects using scope Id as a parameter?

Tags: koin

I have a crypto module that provides my keystore, and a factory that allows me to get a secret key from the keystore based on the key name, like so:

```
var cryptoModule = module {
   single {
      getKeyStore()
   }
   factory { (keyAlias: String) ->
      getKey(keyAlias, get())
   }
}

fun getKeyStore(): KeyStore
fun getKey(keyAlias: String, keyStore: KeyStore) : SecretKey
```

I then want to be able to create a user session, and get back a SecretKey key based on the userId, which is what I use for the scopeId, like so:

```
var sessionModule = module {
   scope(name("SESSION")) {
      scoped(name("sessionKey")) { 
         getKey(ScopeID(), get()
      }
   }
}
```

I'm tryin to get everything going, and I wind up getting crash when I call startKoin and pass it my crypto and session modules - complains about the first parameter to getKey not being provided.  I'm attempting to use it like this:

```
lateinit var userId: String
val sessionScope = getKoin().createScope(userId,name("SESSION"))
val userKey : SecretKey by scope.inject(name("sessionKey"))
```

So, what am I doing wrong?  Can koin support this, or is my thinking about scopes incorrect in some fashion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out.  The scopeId is available as the parameter "id".  I could then create a SecretKey instance using my factory from the crypto module by passing the id to it.

```
val sessionModule = module {
    scope (named("session")) {
        // create a SecretKey, with a named attribute
        scoped(named("sessionKey")) {
            // get it from the factory passing in the scope id
            get<SecretKey> { parametersOf(id) }
        }
        scoped {
            // get the session client and use the named session key
            sessionClient(androidContext(), get(), get(), get(named("sessionKey")))
        }
    }
}
```

The other key was getting access to the value. Because I need to initialize the
session scope with the userId I need to lateinit it, and as such I needed to use the scope.get() method to retrieve an object from the scope.

```
    private lateinit var sessionScope : Scope
    private val sessionClient : OkHttpClient by lazy {
        sessionScope.get<OkHttpClient>()
    }
```

Then as long as I don't try and access sessionClient before setting the sessionScope e.g. (sessionScope =  getKoin().createScope(userId,named("session")), everything works.